# How to install Stock (original android that came with nexus) Android on Rooted Note5?

Tags: root-access

I want to install the stock Android made by originally by Google that is not Samsung modified without breaking the device.

Can I return back after doing this?
How can I do,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't get exactly the same ROM made by Google because Google didn't make one for Note 5. So let's start with ones that are closer to Vanilla.

**Note** - You can skip to the last step if you already have a custom ROM installed.

### Steps for installing custom ROM

#### Install Recovery

Follow the steps to install [TWRP Recovery](https://forum.xda-developers.com/note5/orig-development/twrp-2-8-7-0-official-t3195262) for your device. It will enable you to root your device (sometimes this step is included and need not be done separately) and install a custom by flashing (android lingo) the zip file.

#### Find out your device model

You can find it in one of the following ways

- System - Go to Settings > About
- Back Cover - Printed on the cover or the battery or underneath the battery
- Boot Screen - Restarting the device will show it on screen

#### Download and Install Custom ROM

**Note** - Steps for installation is given in respective ROM's forum.

[Resurrection Remix](https://forum.xda-developers.com/note5/development/resurrectionremixos-6-0-1-t3507572) is a good ROM, giving you vanilla experience with useful extra features.

[Here's](https://forum.xda-developers.com/note5/development) the link for ROMs and other cool stuff for Note 5.

Comment: OP, do note that anything based on AOSP for Exynos 7420 devices is heavily bugged at the moment ("Bugs: too many to count" as said in the XDA thread). If you need the phone to be fully functional then what you want can't really be achieved - blame Samsung for usign Exynos and locking down devices so hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure nexus experience, the best way would be to build yourself a ROM.

It would basically be downloading AOSP code and adding vendor binaries (drivers) so the skill required is much lower than with custom ROMs because you dont need to edit the system itself. 
The instructions can be found on Google developer site and also there is a nice guide on CyanogenMod Wiki site.

The issue here is that the binaries are proprietary and not available most of the time so you wont get the same experience as with the stock ROM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Chapz. I'm currently making a research about a bunch of ways doing this but I want so much to do this. I hate Samsung's modified AndroidOS.

Comment: As a small "workaround" you could customize the stock ROM, I think it would be a better solution considering the situation but you must be very careful about it.

1. Root your phone
2. Delete all system/bloatware apps that you dont need
3. Replace TouchWiz with Google Launcher

You will get a aosp-like feeling, it will run better with unnecessary apps removed and if you add Xposed on top of it you can add features from other ROMs and you keep some beneficial stuff like the Camera which would surely loose quality on other ROMs. Just - be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Different devices has different hardware, which needs different configuration of the OS.
Because of that, **Google releases Stock Android for its devices like Nexus, Android One, Pixel.** Which is the base OS upon which Mobile Companies work and set it for their devices. 
So Basically, you have to be dependent on **Open Source Android Developments.**

*Cyanogen is a very good choice!*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you also edit your answer and add how can I install Cyanogen. I've heard about it but I don't know how to set it up. :D

Comment: And for an extra, in the cyanogen mod wiki, the Note5 is not on the officially supported device list.